# Query won't return $belongs_many_many related object in Silverstripe 3.4

Tags: php, silverstripe, datamodel

I have many `ArticlePage`s, which can appear on many `BlogPage`s, but `ArticlePage::get()->filter('BlogPage.ID', $parentID)` does not return the expected `ArticlePage`s from the database.

I have checked that the pages are published, and the `BlogPage_ArticlePages` table has the relationship stored correctly.

**BlogPage.php**:

```
class BlogPage extends Page {
    ...

    private static $many_many = array(
        'ArticlePages' => 'ArticlePage'
    );

    ...
}
```

**ArticlePage.php**:

```
class ArticlePage extends Page {
    ...
    private static $belongs_many_many = array(
        'BlogPages' => 'BlogPage'
    );
    ...
}
```

**The list/query**:

```
$parentID = 12;
ArticlePage::get()->filter('BlogPages.ID', $parentID);
```

Answer (score 2):

**This worked for me**:

```
$parentID = 12;
$query = ArticlePage::get()->innerJoin(
    $table = '(SELECT "BlogPage_ArticlePages"."ArticlePageID" FROM "BlogPage_ArticlePages" INNER JOIN "BlogPage" ON "BlogPage_ArticlePages"."BlogPageID" = "BlogPage"."ID" WHERE "BlogPage"."ID" = ?)',
    $onClause = '"BlogPage"."ArticlePageID" = "SiteTree"."ID" ',
    $alias = "BlogPage",
    $order = 20,
    $parameters = array($parentID)
);
```

`BlogPage` and `ArticlePage` are both descendants of `SiteTree`, so a more explicit expression is needed to avoid naming conflicts in the resulting query.

Silverstripe developer [TractorCow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4309741/TractorCow) informed me that the way Silverstripe 3 maps queries has some limitations, and gave me the workaround, *but suggested this could be improved even further if time allowed*.

**Explanation**:

When Silverstripe 3 forms an SQL query for descendants of `SiteTree`, it uses the `SiteTree` table (and `SiteTree` "as an alias"). When the `->filter('BlogPage.ID')` is added to the query, Silverstripe uses `SiteTree` as an alias (again). This created a reference conflict, and no records are matched.

The `->innerJoin()` above queries the relevant `BlogPage` data, and aliases it as `BlogPage` instead of `SiteTree`. The `$table` expression within the `( )` is a "cyclical" reference, that provides something we can alias more appropriately.